# Why can I only run this command in the terminal, and not in startup commands nor in the Run command GUI box?

Tags: bash, command-line, linux-mint, command

```
$(run-parts --list --reverse --regex '^KeePassXC-[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]-x86_64\.AppImage' bin | head -n 1)
```

<sub>(The purpose of the above command is to run the most recent version of KeePassXC found in `~/bin`; I don't want to have to modify the startup entry each time I have to upgrade KeePass)</sub>

The above command seem to work *if run from the terminal*. However, if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to get the GUI 'run command' box, I'm getting errors:

```
Failed to execute child process "$(run-parts" (No such file or directory)
```

Even more importantly, similar problem happens if I try to enter this command to Startup Applications:

```
Could not execute '$(run-parts --list --reverse --regex '^KeePassXC-[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]-x86_64\.AppImage' bin | head -n 1)'
Failed to execute child process "$(run-parts" (No such file or directory)
```

I thought that maybe my mistake is that Startup Applications / Run command GUI box run the commands from `/` rather than `~`? So I "fixed" my command, namely I removed `bin` and replaced it with `/home/m/bin` BUT this did not help.

Why am I failing to execute this command from any place BUT the terminal?

Comment: The issue seems to be that the box you're typing this command into is not a shell and can therefor not make sense of you command substitution.  What you could do is to change the single quotes to double quotes and then use the command `sh -c 'you-original-thing'` in the box.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you!

Comment: Note that my last comment is not a proper answer, just a comment. I have no system where I have such a box available and can't test anything that I said in that comment. It just seemed a reasonable explanation and the "solution" follows from that.

Comment: @Kusalananda But it seems to work on my PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message:

```
Could not execute '$(run-parts --list --reverse --regex '^KeePassXC-[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]-x86_64\.AppImage' bin | head -n 1)'
Failed to execute child process "$(run-parts" (No such file or directory)
```

This indicates that the box that you're typing the command into is not a shell, and that it's instead trying to execute the literal command.  A shell would have parsed the command, expanded the command substitution, run the pipeline with `run-parts` and `head` etc.

Since the box is not a shell, and since the command is not a *simple command* (a command, possibly with options), you will have to invoke your original command *with a shell*.  You can do that from the GUI box with the command

```
sh -c 'your command'
```

where `your command` is the command that you initially tried to run (with single quotes replaced by double quotes, because the single quoted argument to `sh -c` can't contain other single quotes).